# how to get list index in java with custom Model

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a Model Class something like this:

```
public class Model {
String title, tag;

public Model() {
}

public Model(String title, String tag) {
    this.title = title;
    this.tag = tag;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getTag() {
    return tag;
}

public void setTag(String tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
}

}
```

So I have `ArrayList<Model> arr;` according to my Model class
so, I want to get the `Index` of the tag for example -

```
//Let Suppose I have ArrayList Like this.

arr.add(new Model("SKYFALL","Action"));
arr.add(new Model("CASINO ROYALE","Thriller"));

//and so on.........
```

For example, I want the index of which have a **`Action`** tag.

I did something like this -
`int index = arr.indexOf("Action");`

but its index is always `-1`

Comment: Does this mean you will only have Object having the `tag` of `Action` ?  If not would you be better off using a `Map` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are finding the index wrong, your array list is of the array of object(Model class) while you find the index using a string.

You need to provide the object to find the index

```
    Model actionModel = new Model("SKYFALL","Action")
    arr.add(actionModel);
    arr.add(new Model("CASINO ROYALE","Thriller"));
```

To find index

```
int index = arr.indexOf(actionModel);
```

**Edit:**
You can run a loop on the array list to find the index of an item

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.size; i++) {
        if (arr.get(i).getTag().eqauls("Action")){
                index = i;
                break;
         }
    }
```

Comment: I have a lot of lists not only one list who have tag with `Action` so please can give answer which apply to my all lists

Comment: You can run loop to find the item , I have updated the code

Comment: After `index = i;` you should `break`

Comment: Yes, sorry , my mistake , thanks @ScaryWombat

Comment: @NitishChaudhary Your Answer is also nice

Answer (score 2):

To get Indexes of Object which contains provided tag. There can be multiple `Model` which has the same tag available.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Model> arr =new ArrayList<>();
      arr.add(new Model("SKYFALL","Action"));
      arr.add(new Model("CASINO ROYALE","Adventure"));
      arr.add(new Model("CASINO ROYALE","Thriller"));
      arr.add(new Model("CASINO ROYALE","Adventure"));

      List<Integer> indexesByTag = getIndexesByTag(arr, "Adventure");;
      System.out.println(indexesByTag);
      // [1, 3]
  }
```

Method to get Indexes of Objects which has provided tag available so need to return `List<Integer>`.

```
public static List<Integer> getIndexesByTag(ArrayList<Model> arr, String action){
    IntStream intStream = IntStream.range(0, arr.size());
    return intStream.boxed()
        .map(index -> {
          if(arr.get(index).getTag().equals(action)){
            return index;
          }
          return -1;
        })
        .filter(index -> index!=-1)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

Other way without stream:

```
public static List<Integer> getIndexesByTag(ArrayList<Model> arr, String action){

    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int index = 0; index < arr.size(); index++) {
      if(arr.get(index).getTag().equals(action)){
        indexes.add(index);
      }
    }
    return indexes;
  }
```

Comment: yeah! Your Answer is also nice but it requires API level 24, my API is 19. so it's working on API 24 but in 19 what can I do?

Comment: @JamesBond. Updated answer.

Comment: Your Answer is also nice

Answer (score 1):

If you check the `indexOf` method code from java library (which internally calls `indexOfRange` method), it return the index by making the `equals` method call on object.

```
int indexOfRange(Object o, int start, int end) {
        Object[] es = elementData;
        if (o == null) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (es[i] == null) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (o.equals(es[i])) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

In your code `equals` will be called on `Model` class object with "Action" string. Which will definitely fail the equality check.

As the solution either override the equals method to return true if either `tag` or `title` matched. But I would say that won't be a good solution because `equals` method should follow some contracts.

So alternatively correct should be use of `Streams` API here.

```
arr.add(new Model("SKYFALL","Action"));
    arr.add(new Model("CASINO ROYALE","Thriller"));
    
    String toMatch = "Action";
    OptionalInt indexOpt = IntStream.range(0, arr.size())
    .filter(i -> toMatch.equals(arr.get(i).tag))
    .findFirst();
    
    System.out.println(indexOpt.orElse(-1)); // 0 Index
```

**Edited:**
If you are using older version of Java (before Java 8), you can use normal for loop as below:

```
int matchedIndex = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size() ; i++) {
      if(arr.get(i).getTag().equals(toMatch)) {
        matchedIndex = i;
        break;
      }
    }
```

So here if `matchedIndex` value after iteration is -1, that means there was no match. Else you will get the matched index.

Comment: Yeah! good answer but `Streams` requires API Level 24 and my is API level 19

Comment: so What can I do which is supported 19 api level also

Comment: For API level 19 you can make use of normal for-loop. I have updated my answer

Comment: What is the value in `System.out.println(indexOpt.getAsInt());` if it is not found?

Comment: @GauravJeswani Your Answer is also nice

Comment: You should specify one argument for `orElse()`.